# Can't make Dynamic dependent dropdown in CodeIgniter with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a dynamic dropdown in Codeigniter using jQuery, but I'm really new to JQuery and it does not work. User first have to choose region and after that he have to choose from a dropdown ot schhols, which are in this region.

My view is:

```
<html>
<head>

   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $('#school').hide();
$('#region').change(function(){
    var region = $('#region').val();
    if (region != ""){
        var post_url = "/index.php/home/register/" + region;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: post_url,
             success: function(school) 
              {
                $('#school').empty();
                $('#school').show();
                   $.each(school,function(school_id,school) 
                   {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                      opt.val(school_id);
                      opt.text(school);
                      $('#school').append(opt); 
                });
               } 
         }); 
    } else {
        $('#school').empty();
        $('#school').hide();
    }
}); 


    </script>  
  </head>
<?php
   echo "<body>";
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo form_open('home/register');

  echo "<h3>Register:</h3><br/>";  
  echo "<table border = '0' >";
  echo "<tr><td>   Username:* </td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'class' => form_error('username') ? 'error' : '',
    'value' => set_value('username')
  );
  echo form_input($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";
//come code register form -passwords and so on..
 echo "<tr><td>  Region:*  </td><td>";
echo "<select name = 'region' id='region' >";
  foreach($regions as $row) 
  {
    echo "<option value= '$row->region '>$row->region</option>";
  } 
  echo "</select>";


   echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td>  School:*  </td><td>";

  echo "<select name = 'school'  id='school'>";

  foreach($school_show as $row) 
  {
    echo "<option value= '$row->school_name '>$row->school_name</option>";
  } 
  echo "</select>";

  echo "</td></tr>";
 echo "<tr ><td>  Class:*  </td><td>";
  $options=array(
    '8' => '8',
    '9' => '9',
    'class' => form_error('class[]') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_dropdown('class[]',$options);
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "</table><br/>";
  $data=array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-success ',
    'id' => 'reg',
    'value' => 'Register'
  );
  echo form_submit($data);
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
```

My controller is:

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->library('session'); 
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();


    }
public function register()
    {
 if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->signup();
        }
        else 
        {  
            if( $this->user_model->register())
            {
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'success_reg'; 
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->model('user_model');   
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'register_form'; 
                $data['regions'] = $this->user_model->regions_show();
                $data['school_show'] = $this->user_model->school_show();
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }   
        }
}
```

My model is:

```
 public function regions_show() {
        $this->db->select('region');
        $this->db->distinct('region'); 
        $this->db->from('schools');  

        $result=$this->db->get();
              return $result->result();

    }
    public function school_show() {
        $this->db->select('school_name'); 

        $this->db->from('schools');  

        $result=$this->db->get();
              return $result->result();

    }
```

Comment: jQuery does not do anything *"in CodeIgniter"*.  JavaScript (jQuery) does not care anything about your framework, PHP or any server-side code.  JavaScript runs in the browser, so all that matters is what's rendered in the browser's source code.   Show us the rendered HTML markup.

Comment: My HTML markup is in the view up after JavaScript.

Comment: I thought my comment was clear enough.  The HTML in in the View is ***NOT*** the "***rendered*** HTML markup".  Rendered markup is the output in the browser source code and would not contain any PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for my register form.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.redexperu.com/assets/js/bootstrap-progressbar/less/bootstrap-progressbar-3.2.0-3.x.x.less">
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9080/survey/css/css.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9080/survey/css/styles/layout.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    <h1></h1>
   <h4 id='header_title'><a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/home/logout">Излез</a></h4>
       <h4 id='header_title'>
   
   </h4>  

    <div id='nav'>            <a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/index/surveys_show">Анкети</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/admin/surveys_manage">Управление на анкети</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/index/results_show">Резултати</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/chart/activity_chart">Диаграма</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/index/student_results_show">Резултати на ученици</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/coordinator/teachers_show">Добави учител</a>
            </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>



  

  <html>
<head>
 
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*function showHide(self, show){
        if (show)
            $('.toggle').show();
        else
            $('.toggle').hide();
        $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
        $(self).prop('checked',true);
    }*/
    </script> 
    <script>
       
  $('#school').hide();
$('#region').change(function(){
    var region = $('#region').val();
    if (region != ""){
        var post_url = "/index.php/home/get_schools/" + region;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: post_url,
             success: function(school) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
              {
                $('#school').empty();
                $('#school').show();
                   $.each(school,function(school_id,school) 
                   {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option for each group
                      opt.val(school_id);
                      opt.text(school);
                      $('#school').append(opt); 
                });
               } 
         }); 
    } else {
        $('#school').empty();
        $('#school').hide();
    }
}); 


    </script>  
     <style>

  form input {
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body><div class='container'><form action="http://localhost:9080/survey/index.php/home/register" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><h3>Регистрация:</h3><br/><table border = '0' ><tr><td>   Потребителско име:* </td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td> Парола:* </td><td><input type="password" name="password" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td>  Повтори парола:* </td><td><input type="password" name="password2" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td>  Име:*  </td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td>  Фамилия:*  </td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td>  Населено място:*  </td><td><input type="text" name="location" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td>  Имейл:*  </td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="" class=""  /></td></tr><tr><td>  Изберете роля:*  </td><td><input type="radio" name="role_id[]" value="1" onClick="showHide(this, true)" /> Ученик <input type="radio" name="role_id[]" value="2" onClick="showHide(this, true)" /> Учител <input type="radio" name="role_id[]" value="5" onClick="showHide(this, false)" /> Координатор </td></tr><tr><td>  Регион:*  </td><td><select name = 'region[]' id='region' ><option value= 'Враца '>Враца</option><option value= 'София '>София</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>  Училище:*  </td><td><select name = 'school[]'  id='school'><option value= 'ПМГ "Акад. Иван Ценов" '>ПМГ "Акад. Иван Ценов"</option><option value= 'СОУ "Христо Ботев" '>СОУ "Христо Ботев"</option><option value= 'ЕГ '>ЕГ</option><option value= 'ПМГ '>ПМГ</option></select></td></tr><tr ><td>  Клас:*  </td><td><select name="class[]">
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="class"></option>
</select></td></tr></table><br/><input type="submit" name="" value="Регистрация" class="btn btn-success " id="reg"  /></form></div></body></html>
```